# How to set the dockerfile and environment variables while making lambda in CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk

I have SAM project in `template.yml`

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30
    Environment:
      Variables:
        DBNAME: !Ref DBNAME

Resources:
  MessageFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        Message:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /message
            Method: post
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile.message
      DockerContext: ./botapp
      DockerTag: python3.9-v1
```

then deploy like this

`sam deploy --guided --parameter-overrides DBNAME=mydb`

It means I will set environment variables `DBNAME=mydb` and build image from `Dockerfile.message`.

It works well for now.

However now I want to move this to `cdk`

So, in cdk I first wrote this code

```
const messageLambda = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "BotLambda", {
  code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset("chatbot-sam/botapp"),
});
```

However I want to set the `dockerfile` and `environment variables`.

For example

```
const messageLambda = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "BotLambda", {
  code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(
         "chatbot-sam/botapp",
         dockerfile: Dockerfile.message,
         enviroment_variables: { DBNAME:'mydb'}
       ),
});
```

Above code is not correct, however my idea is ok?

How can I indicate `Dockerfile` and `environment variables`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [the `DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset()` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.html#static-fromwbrimagewbrassetdirectory-props), you can specify a relative path to the Dockerfile in the `file` parameter.

As for environment variables for the lambda itself, [the docs for `lambda.DockerImageFunction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction.html#environment) explain this as well. You define the environment variable with the `environment` attribute:

> environment?
>
> Type: { [string]: string } (optional, default: No environment
> variables.)
>
> Key-value pairs that Lambda caches and makes available for your Lambda
> functions.

So it would look like this:

```
const messageLambda = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "BotLambda", {
  code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(
         "chatbot-sam/botapp",
         {
            file: "Dockerfile.message",
         }
       ),
  environment: { DBNAME:'mydb'}
});
```

Comment: thank you veyr much ! but `file` properties are in AssetImageCodeProps so maybe `code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(
        "chatbot-sam/chatbotapp",
        {
          "file": "Dockerfile.message"
        }
      ),
      environment:{
        
      }`

Comment: Correct, updated the answer.